# Loop Through Folder & Copy Specific Worksheet to New Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am looking for a macro to loop through a folder and copy the worksheets labeled "Working Copy" from many workbooks and paste these as their own worksheet on a new workbook that the macro creates ("Working Copies") that will be saved in the same folder. I am working on a Mac. In a perfect world, the new tab names would be labeled the name of the file they came from. I will be duplicating this to be run again but for a different tab name/different end file. I am adding this to an already existing macro where I have asked the user to select a folder and then a macro is run on each of the files within the folder and saved. This is the last piece that I am struggling to find a solution to. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub CopySheets()
    Dim sourceFolder As String
    Dim destinationFile As String
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wbDestination As Workbook
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim fileExtension As String
    Dim fileName As String
    
    ' Set the source folder where the workbooks are located
    sourceFolder = "/Users/sj/Desktop/Folder"
    
    ' Set the file extension of the workbooks you want to copy from
    fileExtension = "*.xlsx"
    
    ' Set the destination file where the copied sheets will be saved
    destinationFile = "/Users/sj/Desktop/Folder/Working Copies.xlsx"
    
    ' Create a new workbook as the destination workbook
    Set wbDestination = Workbooks.Add
    
    ' Loop through all the files in the source folder with the specified file extension
    fileName = Dir(sourceFolder & fileExtension)
    Do While fileName <> ""
        ' Open the source workbook
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(sourceFolder & fileName)
        
        ' Loop through all the sheets in the source workbook
        For Each wsSource In wbSource.Sheets
            ' Check if the sheet name matches a specific tab name
            Select Case wsSource.Name
                Case "Working Copy"
                    ' Copy the sheet to the destination workbook
                    Set wsDestination = wbDestination.Sheets.Add
                    wsSource.Copy wsDestination
                    wsDestination.Name = wbSource.Name & " - " & wsSource.Name
            End Select
        Next wsSource
        
        ' Close the source workbook
        wbSource.Close False
        
        ' Move to the next file in the source folder
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop
    
    ' Save and close the destination workbook
    wbDestination.SaveAs destinationFile
    wbDestination.Close False
End Sub
```

This will create the 'Working Copies' file and save it to the folder but it does not copy the tabs from the workbooks in the folder.

Comment: it looks as if you are missing a path separator character (in your case a slash) at the end of your source path, resulting in a command `Dir "/Users/sj/Desktop/Folder*.xlsx"`

Comment: @FunThomas Appreciate your quick response! I have added that and now it's giving me an error at `wsDestination.Name = wbSource.Name & " - " & wsSource.Name`. It created the new workbook, copied the tab from the first file in the folder, and then 2 blank sheets. It now does not save the new workbook or alter the name of the new workbook. 

Run-time error '1004'
You typed in an invalid name for a sheet or chart. Make sure that:
-The name that you type does not exceed 31 characters

Comment: The answer is right there at the end of your comment?  You need to ensure any name you give to a chart/worksheet etc is valid.  See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-a-worksheet-3f1f7148-ee83-404d-8ef0-9ff99fbad1f9#:~:text=Important%3A%C2%A0%20Worksheet%20names%20cannot%3A

Comment: @TimWilliams yup - I'm an idiot, math is hard  thanks!

I have updated that line to be `wsDestination.Name = wbSource.Name`. This is now looping through correctly but inserting additional tabs. The tabs that I have copied keep their 'Working Copy' name and now the file it was pulled from is a new blank tab. How can I make the tab copied to have the name of the file it was pulled from?

Comment: `wsSource.UsedRange.Copy wsDestination.Range("A1")` maybe